# A way to check if camera is available through broadcastreceiver?

Tags: android

I'm trying to find a way to check if the camera is available every second on an android phone and I've learned if I use a timer to check every second it'll kill the battery extremely fast, so I was wondering and I've searched is there a way to use BroadcastReciever to notify I.E Toast or something that each time the camera is being used, I do not want it each time a picture is taken. I'm currently making an app that notifys you if your camera is in use which is why I need to check if the camera is available every second. If you have any other ideas on how to do this please let me know.

Comment: Why you want to check camera is available in every second.If u check only once when app started its enough.

Comment: The reason is because I'm developing an app that lets you know if your camera is being used I.E If you were using Snapchat, it'd notify you that your camera is being used.